# Will GIL interfere if I run my python code with multiprocessing in it on different virual machine on the same pc?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, gil

I currently have a python scripts that scrapes data from a single url.

In order to speed up the process I'm using the pool multiprocessing module in the script, this script is called "script_one.py" for the sake of explanation.

The script it exclusively does a "get request" to collect the json/html resuls from the target url and constantly switches proxy address, and saves the results on a text file.

My question is: 
If I run the same code (script_one.py) on multiple virtual machine, will I further speed up the process without incurring into any issue with GIL?

Here below is my code:

```
import requests,time,random
from multiprocessing import Pool


def script_one(file_name,from_letter,to_letter):
    print('Here it does the get request and collects data')
    print('Here it saves on file')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.starmap(script_one,[('r_ba', 'r', 'rba'),('rbrca', 'rb', 'rca'),('rcrda', 'rc', 'rda'),
                                 ('rdrea', 'rd', 'rea'),('rerfa', 're', 'rfa'),('rfrga', 'rf', 'rga'),
                                 ('rgrha', 'rg', 'rha'),('rhria', 'rh', 'ria'),('rirja', 'ri', 'rja'),
                                 ('rjrka', 'rj', 'rka'),('rkrla', 'rk', 'rla'),('rlrma', 'rl', 'rma'),
                                 ('rmrna', 'rm', 'rna'),('rnroa', 'rn', 'roa'),('rorpa', 'ro', 'rpa'),
                                 ('rprqa', 'rp', 'rqa'),('rqrra', 'rq', 'rra'),('rrrsa', 'rr', 'rsa'),
                                 ('rsrta', 'rs', 'rta'),('rtrua', 'rt', 'rua'),('rurva', 'ru', 'rva'),
                                 ('rvrwa', 'rv', 'rwa'),('rwrxa', 'rw', 'rxa'),('rxrya', 'rx', 'rya'),
                                 ('ryrza', 'ry', 'rza'),('rzr0a', 'rz', 'r0a')]))

         p.close()
         p.join()
```

Comment: So, your question basically is: "Will I get more and more computing power if I run more virtual machines on one computer?", right?

Comment: You don't need multiple virtual machines (although that will work). Just multiple processes wont clash GILs

Comment: Also, AFAIK requests does release the GIL when waiting on a socket, so you may not even need multiple processes, just multiple threads. Besides, if you have to do a lot of requests in parallel the right tool is probably async IO.

Comment: @ChrisCharles, thanks, so I will not encounter any major performance change by simply using one script with multiprocessing module?

Comment: @MatteoItalia, thanks, I'll look into async IO, if I understand correctly, I could just use one single process but launched in many different threads?

Comment: @ForceBru, thanks, the main idea is to divide IE: brute-forcing with request a list in alphabetic order for example, but instead of going from a to z with one process, to divide all the alphabet by letter and then send the same process on each letter simultaneously! Just trying to understand how much can I leverage this without having issues of bottleneck by GIL.

Comment: @SkylerX with multithread you can still use synchronous IO; with async io you don't even need multiple threads.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, thanks. Kindly post is as reply so I can assign the answer.

Comment: i think he means to run the script several times in parallel in the same machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there are multiple options available:
 - Multi-processing
 - Multi-threading 
 - Using multiple virtual machine in parallel
 - For windows user, I also found a good way to use multiple desktop (I'm guessing should work the same for linux users)
 - Also you can manually run multiple terminals windows at the same time, as (Credit: @MatteoItalia) during request, while waiting for socket GIL gets released.

Credit: @MatteoItalia